# Cannot ping github.com or git clone via terminal (Ubuntu WSL)

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I am able to ping websites like google.com, facebook.com, and cnet.com perfectly fine, but get timeout when trying to ping github.com. For some reason I'm also getting timeout when pinging duckduckgo.com as well. (results are identical pinging with either Ubuntu or windows cmd terminal). I even tried pinging on my phone (both on my wifi and on data), same result.

I am also unable to do git clone via ssh in WSL2 Ubuntu. Are these problems related? Cloning with the github desktop app does work though.

The strangest thing is that last week I was able to clone a repository with git clone in WSL ubuntu perfectly fine. I'm completely baffled. Any suggestions?

Edit: Cloning with git bash command line works, it just seems like my WSL Ubuntu cannot clone for some reason. It's just stuck and never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if you were cloning using HTTPS or SSH.

Second, see if you can contact github.com (unless this is a [DNS issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260072/5470)) on those ports with:

```bash
# For SSH    
curl -v telnet://github.com:22
# For HTTPS
curl -v telnet://github.com:443

# OR, if github.com is not resolved by your DNS
# For SSH    
curl -v telnet://140.82.121.3:22
# For HTTPS
curl -v telnet://140.82.121.3:443
```

Comment: I am using SSH, and it has worked before just last week to clone something. both curl commands work, with last line being something like `Connected to github.com (20.205.243.166) port 22 (#0)`. I figure something might be wrong with my WSL ubuntu because I can successfully clone stuff with the github desktop app.

Comment: @Nole OK. Sounds like a DNS issue. Would https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5256#issuecomment-636361926 help?

Comment: that didn't help me :(. I asked a classmate to try pinging github.com for me as well. We noticed something new. The hosts resolved differently. My ping "github.com" resolved to (20.205.243.166) but her ping "github.com" resolved to (140.82.112.3). Apparently my computer is pinging a Singapore ip (due to my location being closer) and she is pinging the San Francisco ip (she is in the US). I am able to get a response from pinging the San Francisco ip, but not the Singapore one. So this makes me wonder if it could also be a server-side issue, not just something wrong with my computer.

Comment: This is exactly same with my problem. I can browse github.com or 20.205.243.166 but I can't ping nor clone them.

Comment: @panoet Also from WSL? Using HTTPS or SSH GitHub URL?